# Java compare int arrays, filter and insert or update to DB

Tags: java, arrays

I have written an app which helps organize home bills. The problem is that in one home can live more than one person, and one person can have more than one home (e.g. me - in both cases :) ). So I've decided to give the user a possibility to bind a contractor (payment receiver) to multiple users and multiple homes.

In my data base there are concatenation tables between accounts and contractors and between homes and contractors. Great, isn't it?

Now, the point is that I'm getting a list of related users (or houses) as sql array, and I finally keep it as Integer[] array. I've made some dummy database entries, so I can test the functionality and it works fine.

But... I have completely no idea how should I properly store changed values in database. The structure of my tables are:

Users
id | username | ....
1 | user1 | ...
2 | user2 | ...

Contractors
id | name | ...
1 | contractor1 | ...

users_contractors
user_id | contractor_id | is_deleted
1 | 1 | false
1 | 2 | false
etc .....

So what I have is: an array of users related to contractor and the second array of users related to contrator (the modified one). Now I need to store the values in DB. When user + contractor does not exists - i need to insert that relation. If it already exists in database, but does not exist in my array (e.g. the connection was deleted) - i need to update the relation table and marked as deleted=true.

I've found some solutions on how to compare two arrays, but they all assume that the arrays are the same length, and they compare values with the same index only.

So what I need is to compare not arrays as we speak, but the array values (if one array contains values from another array, or the opposite). Can this be achieved without forloop-in-forloop ?

Thank you in advance.
Tom

Comment: Did you consider using an ORM solution to address your need? I think it will help you get rid of most of your problems related to design of objects and updating the values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully: You have an array of user IDs, and an array of contractor IDs, and you need to update the database so that all the users of array 1 are related to all contractors of array 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are using arrays instead of Lists/Collections? These can help you search for items and make it easier to compare two of them.

I don't have an IDE at hand now, so here is some pseudocode:

```
// Create a list with all the values (maybe use a hashset to prevent duplicates)
List<int> all = new List();
all.addAll(A);
all.addAll(B);

//for each loop
for (int i : all) {
    boolean inA = A.contains(i);
    boolean inB = B.contains(i);
    if (inA && inB) {
    // You can figure out the rest of these statements I think
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, actually - I'm getting an Array from DB (Select c.id, array_agg(u.id) from contractor c join accounts_contractors u...), so I've figured out - it will be the easiest way to preselect values in TwinColSelect field from Vaadin framework.

Now, I have some doubts... :)

Comment: So what am I supposed to do until then if I want to help the asker?

Comment: @DrIvol I've made some corrections to my code. Now I store data in List<Integer>. So the situation is, that I need to know a status for each value in both list: valA not in listB, valB not exists in listA, valA/valB exists in listB/listA. So, basically, here is what i need:

if(!listA.contains(valB)) - insert new row,
if(!listB.contains(valA)) - update existing row (deleted),
if(valA==valB) - nothing has changed, nothing to do.

Comment: @T.Fruba I have edited my answer with something that I think that will work.

Comment: You could do this with a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the ID of the Object (Might be an Object) and the value the number of occurence. Insert every A **distinct** with a value of 1. Once this is done, for each values in B, check if it exist, if so increment the value, if not, create it (if duplicate in B is needed). Every values greater than 1 is in both list

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DrIvol - I've managed to solve the issue using the code:

```
List<Integer> allUsers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    allUsers.addAll(bean.getUserId());
    allUsers.addAll(bean.getNewUserId());
    for(Integer i : allUsers) {
        Boolean oldValue = bean.getUserId().contains(i);
        Boolean newValue = bean.getNewUserId().contains(i);
        if(oldValue && newValue) {
            System.out.println(i + " value in both lists");
            // Nothing to do
        } else if (oldValue && !newValue) {
            System.out.println(i + " value removed");
            // Set value as deleted
        } else if(!oldValue && newValue) {
            System.out.println(i + " value added");
            // Insert new value to concat table
        }
    }
```

It has one problem: If the value was on the first list, and it still is in the second list (no modification) - it's checked twice. But, since I don't need to do anything with this value - it's acceptable for now. Someday, when I'll finish beta version - I'll be doing some optimisations, so I'll make some deduplicator for the list :)

Thank you very much!

Tom

Comment: Thanks for mentioning me! In order to prevent checking for duplicates you could change `List<Integer> allUsers = new ArrayList<Integer>();` to `Set<Integer> allUsers = new HashSet<Integer>();`. HashSets automatically ignore duplicate values if I remember correctly. The loop should work as it does now, but it doesn't do it in order anymore.

Comment: I don't care 'bout an order. I'll give HashSet a try, but first I need to build first beta version - it's my priority :) After that - I'll have more time for cleaning and optimisation...